# How to limit a Type type to a specific types subset in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, types, syntax

A variable of type `Type` can contain any type. What I need is a variable that can only contain types that inherit a specific class and implement a specific interface. How can this be specified? I have tried declaring the variable as

```
Type: MyClass, IMyInterface theTypeVariable;
```

and as

```
Type<MyClass, IMyInterface> theTypeVariable;
```

but neither works.

what's the correct way?

For example

```
class A {...}

class B {...}

interface IC {...}

interface ID {...}

class E: B, IC {...}

class F: B, IC, ID {...}

class G: ID {...}

...

// This following line invalid actually,
// so it is pseudocode of a kind
// the syntactically and semantically correct form of this is the question
Type: B, IC theTypeVariable; // or Type<B, IC> theTypeVariable // perhaps

theTypeVariable = typeof(E); // This assignment is to be valid.

theTypeVariable = typeof(F); // This assignment is to be valid.

theTypeVariable = typeof(A); // This assignment is to be invalid.

theTypeVariable = typeof(B); // This assignment is to be invalid.

theTypeVariable = typeof(IC); // This assignment is to be invalid.

theTypeVariable = typeof(G); // This assignment is to be invalid.
```

For a more definite example: I may want to declare a type variable that can only contain any types that extend `List<T>` and implement `IDisposable` (a disposable list of Ts, not a list of disposables).

E.g. I will implement `DisposableList<T>: List<T>, IDisposable` and `AnotherDisposableListImplementation<T>: List<T>, IDisposable` classes and I want a variable that will be able to store `typeof(DisposableList<Foo>)` and `typeof(AnotherDisposableListImplementation<Foo>)` but not `typeof(Foo)` nor `typeof(List<Foo>)`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here at all.

Comment: @DavidG Ok, give me a moment, I'll add examples. Thank you for feedback.

Comment: Are you referring to generics ?

Comment: So no, what you're asking isn't possible, and it's also not clear why you would even want to do that. This smells a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: A Type variable can contain any Type value as an Int32 variable can contain any Int32 value. There is no difference in handling

Comment: @SirRufo "A Type variable can contain any Type" - what I want is a type variable that can only contain, for example, any types that extend `List<T>` and implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Then why not a `List<IDisposable>`?

Comment: @DavidG Because I need a disposable list of something, not a list of disposables, `T` in `List<T>` is a type that does not Implement `IDisposable` (in this example).

Comment: But `List<T>` isn't disposable. What exactly are you trying to dispose?

Comment: @DavidG The list. That's why I will implement `DisposableList<T>: List<T>, IDisposable` and `AnotherDisposableListImplementation<T>: List<T>, IDisposable` classes and I want a variable that will be able to store `typeof(DisposableList<Foo>)` and `typeof(AnotherDisposableListImplementation<Foo>)` but not `typeof(Foo)` nor `typeof(List<Foo>)`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but you're making less sense as this goes on, I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Good luck trying to sort this out :)

Comment: @Ivan I know what you want, but my comment should have shown you that it is impossible with a Type variable as it is impossible to restrict certain Int32 values for a Int32 variable. But you can build a struct that will only accept "valid" type values

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
 public class EstentedList<Type> where Type:List<T>,IDisposable
 {

 }
```

you can use this class as Type for your variables

Comment: How does this stop a particular type being stored in a `Type` variable?

Answer (score 0):

`Type` contains metadata about a type; it is part of the reflection API. This is not valid:

```
Type x = 5;
Type y = "Hello Sailor!";
```

To have a type `U` which is a subtype of `T` and implements interface `I` you can use generics:

```
... Foo<U>(...)
where U : T, I
{
  U myvar;
}
```

You can create a new type in this way:

```
class MyType : MyClass, IMyInterface
{
  private MyClass A;
  private IMyInterface B;

  private MyType(MyClass a, IMyInterface b)
  {
    A = a;
    B = b;
  }

  public static MyType Create<U>(U x)
  where U : MyClass, IMyInterface
  {
    return new MyType(x, x);
  }

  // Implementations of MyClass and IMyInterface
  // which delegate to A and B.

}
```

Now variables with type `MyType` are a subtype of `MyClass` and `IMyInterface`.